# how to apply Fitter (fitter package is a Python library for fitting probability distributions to data) object to a bar chart instead of a histogram

Tags: python-3.x, histogram, distribution

Dear Stack Overflow enthusiasts,

I have the following python list = [0.087, 0.051, 0.556, 0.053, 0.0, 0.0, 0.149, 0.104, 0.0, 0.0].

I want to figure out to which distribution this list belongs too. The fitter package (https://fitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) allows you to upload a dataset. However, it automatically creates a histogram based on the data. And this is not what I want. I don't want the number of observations to be counted.

What I want is that the list is used in order. Hence, on the y-axis the first value is 0.0.87, the next value is 0.051 etc. Based on this the data distribution should be determined.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

I tried to find for a solution on the internet and Stack Overflow, but I could not find one.

Comment: you have told the community what you dont want. But how about telling the community what you want to achieve. provide a worked example:  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How about you make samples according to you bars? No need to randomize